# Has Batman ever time-traveled in any form?

Tags: time-travel, batman, dc

Some of the main DC characters have time-traveled such as the Flash and Superman, has Batman in any serial ever traveled through time?

Comment: He's been in different times quite a few times in the [Elseworlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elseworlds#Noted_titles) line, but it's not really time-travel. (Just in case you wanted any other info about him being in the past or future.)

Comment: Batman has travelled in time on numerous occasions in comic and tv formats; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Return_of_Bruce_Wayne, http://nothingbutbatman.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/batmans-travels-through-time.html, http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Issue_112

Comment: Batman experiences constant time travel at a rate of approximately 1 week every 604800 seconds.

Comment: Even if your question was: **What hasn't Bats done?**  The answer would have to be: He's been everywhere man and done everything... After all, he is _THE BATMAN_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batman also time-travelled a couple of times in *The Brave and the Bold* in order to team up with Kamandi in the future, for example in [The Brave and the Bold #120](http://www.comics.org/issue/28733/).

But then Brave & Bold was always in its own (lack of) continuity.

Answer (score 5):

In the [Return of Bruce Wayne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3a_The_Return_of_Bruce_Wayne), there are time travel elements.

Comment: What are these elements? If you expanded this, it would make for a better  answer :)

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have pointed out, *The Return of Bruce Wayne* is probably the "biggest" example of a Batman time travel story, in terms of continuity.

> It covers Bruce jumping through various different time periods, slowly returning to the future after having been apparently killed (but actually sent back in time) during the events of *Final Crisis*.

Since you asked for any serial, I'll also mention "The Once and Future Thing", a two-part episode of the *Justice League* animated series, which features members of the League (Batman, Green Lantern, and Wonder Woman) tracking down a time-travelling villain. The first episode features various DC Western-era heroes such as Jonah Hex and the second is set in the future of the *Batman Beyond* cartoon (albeit with the timeline altered by the villain), which leads to [the wonderful team-up between modern Batman and elderly Bruce Wayne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PETk8eBbfN0).

A recent arc in the *Batman '66* comic (starting in digital issue #22) also had King Tut travelling back in time to ancient Egypt, with Batman and Robin following him.

That's a handful of examples but I've no doubt there are plenty more, even if Batman isn't as involved with time travel as the Flash (who has it as an inherent part of his powers, with the assistance of his Cosmic Treadmill, and who has several time-travelling enemies) or Superman (with his long-standing association with casual time travellers, the Legion of Superheroes). Time travel stories and the alternate universes they create are a remarkably common occurrence in comics and Batman has been in a *lot* of comics over the years.

Answer (score 4):

Batman time travels in both **Justice League** episode *The Once and Future Thing* and the **Batman the Brave and the Bold** episode *Menace of the Madniks!*

The sheer volume of Batman fiction in print and video means that it will be difficult to give a complete answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Batman: The Animated Series" Episode "Time Out of Joint" Batman and Robin battle The Clock King who has a device which can stop time allowing him to move through time quickly as if teleporting. Later in the episode Batman and Robin meet up with the scientist who created the time device which The Clock King stole from him and have to end up using the same kind of time device to quickly get to their location in time to foil The Clock King's plan to kill Mayor Hamilton Hill with a bomb. The episode can be seen here:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x48qyye

Comment: So, do they travel to the past/future, or do they use a time-manipulation device to travel in space?